# Looping letters and numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of letters and *then* looping thorugh numbers, however, I'm running into problems.

The problem is that the letters won't stop looping.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int inuti(double x, double y, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
  int x_inuti;
  int y_inuti;

  if (x1 < x2)
    x_inuti = x > x1 && x < x2;
  else
    x_inuti = x > x2 && x < x1;
  if (y1 < y2)
    y_inuti = y > y1 && y < y2;
  else
    y_inuti = y > y2 && y < y1;
  return x_inuti && y_inuti;
}

int main(void) {
  double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;
  char text_x, text_y, text_x1, text_y1, text_x2, text_y2;
  int resultat;
  int i, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6;

  char tecken[] = "ab";// cdefgABCDEFG. + -";
  char teckenback[] = "-+";// .GFEDXBAgfedcba";
  int max;
  int maxback;
  max = strlen(tecken);
  maxback = strlen(teckenback);

      //This is the number loop     
  for (x = 0; x <= 3; x+=0.1) {
    for (y = 0; y <= 3; y+=0.1) {
      for (x1 = 0; x1 <= 3; x1+=0.1) {
        for (y1 = 0; y1 <= 3; y1+=0.1) {
          for (x2 = 0; x2 <= 3; x2+=0.1) {
            for (y2 = 0; y2 <= 3; y2 += 0.1){

              printf("punktens x-varde: %.1f \n", x);


              printf("punktens y-varde: %.1f \n", y);

              printf("\n");

              printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %.1f \n", x1);


              printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %.1f \n", y1);

              printf("\n");

              printf("Andra hornets x-varde %.1f \n", x2);


              printf("Andra hornets y-varde %.1f \n", y2);

              printf("\n");
              resultat = inuti(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2);


              if (resultat == 1)
                printf("Punkten var inuti rektangeln.\n");
              else
                printf("Punkten var utanfor rektangeln.\n");

              printf("\n");
              printf("\n");

            //This is the letter loop. The problem is that it never stops here. But if commenting away the number loop, this runs and stops without a problem
              for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                for (i2 = 0; i2 < maxback; i2++) {
                  for (i3 = 0; i3< max; i3++) {
                    for (i4 = 0; i4 < maxback; i4++) {
                      for (i5 = 0; i5 < max; i5++) {
                        for (i6 = 0; i6 < maxback; i6++) {

                          text_x = tecken[i];
                          text_y = teckenback[i2];
                          text_x1 = tecken[i3];
                          text_y1 = teckenback[i4];
                          text_x2 = tecken[i5];
                          text_y2 = teckenback[i6];

                          printf("punktens x-varde: %c \n", text_x);


                          printf("punktens y-varde: %c \n", text_y);

                          printf("\n");

                          printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %c \n", text_x1);


                          printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %c \n", text_y1);

                          printf("\n");

                          printf("Andra hornets x-varde %c \n", text_x2);


                          printf("Andra hornets y-varde %c \n", text_y2);

                          printf("\n");

                          printf("##### Endast nummer tillatet! #####");
                          printf("\n");
                          printf("\n");

                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }       
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

When I commented the number loop, the letter loop worked perfectly. But somehow they can't work together. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: It runs as expected for me - each "letter loop" eventually ends after 64 inner loop executions, then the `y2` is slighty incremented and the letters start all over again.

Comment: Number loops includes another loop, which is letter loop. Outer (Number) loop count is 729000000 (30^6). And there is printf's in loops. Loop will end, if you wait for enough time (maybe 1~2 day).

Comment: @PaulRoub The letter start all over again? It is supposed to stop looping completely and start looping the letters after it's done looping the letters

Comment: You mean "after it's done looping the *numbers*"? If so, you probably don't want the letter loop *inside* the number loop.

Comment: @OnurTurhan I know that the number loop will take a long time to loop. But the letter loop is short and I want it to start looping the numbers after the letter loop is finished

Comment: Fixed the indentation of the code, to highlight the fact that the letter loop is *inside* the number loop, and so will run *every* time the number loop increments.

Comment: @PaulRoub Sorry I was meant to say that I want the number loop to start after the letter loop.

Comment: Then you should, again, move the letter loop *out* of the number loop - and place it *before* the number loop.

Comment: @PaulRoub I did try to do that at first, but when running the code, it doesn't save the letter loop in the compiler when starting to loop the numbers

Comment: @PaulRoub as soon as it begins to loop the numbers after the letter loop, the letter loops disappears and you're not able to scroll up in the compiler to check on it

Comment: @PaulRoub And i though the reason for this was because they are in different loops that's why i tried to nest them together

Comment: So you want want to run before the other, but... you also want them both running at the same time? I confess, at this point I have *no* idea what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: @PaulRoub I want the letter to loop before the number, yes. But as the number starts to run I want to be able to scroll up in the compiler and check the letter loop. The problem is that when the number loop starts to loop after the letter loop, the letter loop disappears from the compiler.